# Find exact value of VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL for laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a laravel + Vue.js project template downloaded from Creative Tim. Its login and register is not proceeding, giving the catch error whereas in the template demo its working fine. I think so the instructions said to write the VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL in Vue .env file and I didn't wrote it correct. Can anyone pls tell me how can I locate the exact address and what syntax it would be?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using vue with laravel, you need to prefix `MIX_` before the variable. Eg:

```
MIX_VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

Here is the reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#environment-variables